# Displaying PDF ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a file on my desktop for test. I am trying to display it in a view that looks like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowFile";
}

<h2>ShowFile</h2>
```

The code I am using for the controller is:

```
   [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ShowFile(string path)
        {
            path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\nickla\Desktop\nlamarca_06_15.pdf";

            return File(path, "application/pdf", "nlamarca_06_15.pdf");
        }
```

When I run this code the view displays "undefined" any ideas on what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't seem to have specified the filename in your path:

```
public ActionResult ShowFile(string filename)
{
    var path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\nickla\Desktop";
    var file = Path.Combine(path, filename);
    file = Path.GetFullPath(file);
    if (!file.StartsWith(path))
    {
        // someone tried to be smart and sent 
        // ?filename=..\..\creditcard.pdf as parameter
        throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
    }
    return File(file, "application/pdf");
}
```

Comment: What view are you talking about? There's no view here. The controller action returns the file directly.

Comment: do I have do something more to ShowFile.cshtml to display the files contents? Should I remove the view all together?

Comment: You could completely remove this view. To invoke your controller action you simply navigate to `/home/showfile` in your browser (replace `home` with the name of the controller containing the `ShowFile` action if necessary).

Comment: ahhh - this little nugget of info (the presence of ShowFile.cshtml) reveals the issue now!! slowly but surely teasing a problem out :)

Comment: Do you think creating the view is messing this up?

Comment: No, the view is not used at all. Nobody is calling it if your controller action returns a File as shown here. You could leave it if you want, it won't change anything. What happens when you navigate to `/home/showfile` in your browser (assuming the `ShowFile` action looks exactly as I showed in my answer)?

Comment: Removing the view downloads the file, but I want to display the files contents in the browser. Also to invoke this in my real application I need to get the path from a query string, but there is no view to attach the querystring to in this case

Comment: Alright, if you want to display the file in the browser simply remove the third argument of the File method: `return File(path, "application/pdf");`. I will update my answer to show how you could pass the filename as parameter in a second.

Comment: The pressence of the querystring in the url makes it "undefined" again http://localhost:59527/Home/ShowFile/20-699 where "20-699" is the parameter value makes the output display "undefined" ..this controller method is being called view this href="@Url.Action("ShowFile","Home", new { partnumber = ViewBag.PartNumber })"

Comment: @NickLaMarca, I see that you are using the `partnumber` route token in your link. In this case make sure that your controller action uses the same name for the parameter: `public ActionResult ShowFile(string partnumber)`. Also I assume that you have a corresponding route defined. Also since `20-699` doesn't contain the extension make sure that your controller action adds it. And please show your actual real if you need further help. Just look at your question. It has strictly nothing to do with what you are talking now in the comments.

Comment: a corresponding route defined? How/Where do I that maybe thats the issue? When I create views I never define a route anywhere

Comment: Routes are defined in your Global.asax file. In the `Application_Start` method. Do you know what a route is in ASP.NET MVC? In ASP.NET MVC views are not directly accessed. Only controller actions. The way which controller action will be invoked from a given url depends on your routing definition.

Comment: sorry i will start a new question thanks for your help on this one

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the file name in the path. your path only up to the directory. Give the full PDF file name.

```
public ActionResult ShowFile(string path)
{
   //not sure why you overwrote although you have a parameter to pass the path

    path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\nickla\Desktop\nlamarca_06_15.pdf";
    return File(path, "application/pdf", "nlamarca_06_15.pdf");
}
```

Assuming the PDF file name you have in that particular directory is `nlamarca_06_15.pdf`

Comment: this returns the word "undefined" to the view

Comment: Make sure you have the file exist in that path.

Comment: this file is on my desktop, I am running the application via localhost

Comment: Try moving the file to a different location and see ( Ex : C:\\nlamarca_06_15.pdf). Make sure to edit your path in the code also. And are you passing the path parameter value in url ?

Answer (score 0):

Nick,

Appears at 1st look to be a path issue (no filename, only path), try:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ShowFile(string path)
{
    path = @"C:\Documents and Settings\nickla\Desktop\nlamarca_06_15.pdf";

    return File(path, "application/pdf", "pdf_download_name.pdf");
}
```

the final parameter is purely the name that you want the downloaded file to be given as it 'hits' the users local drive.

**[Edit]** I see you've updated your question, which invalidates all of the suggestions so far. The only addition that I can see is that you may not have a route setup that handles the path parameter. this question could be a moving target :)